# saffire pro 40 programming api

Tags: audio-interfaces, programming

I don't usually work with audio equipment but for now I've got access to a Saffire Pro 40. Setup is pretty straight forward and the Mix Control is easy to use.

I am trying to programmatically control the volume for an input channel instead of using the Mix Control application. I was going though the site and sound card manual but I couldn't find an API or SDK.

Is there a way to programmatically control volume on a Saffire Pro 40 sound card ? If so, how ? Otherwise, what are the alternatives ?

Comment: As you have seen yourself, it seems that this sound card does not offer a programmable interface. As for the alternatives, we would need to know what you are trying to achieve by 'programmatically control the volume for an input channel'

Comment: Well, I'm making some progress with Port Audio and it's Python bindings(pyaudio), but so far that is manually streaming data from inputs/outputs and scaling them accordingly. I was hoping to find some sort of API allowing me to change the volume of a channel without streaming that channel's data and multiplying the signal myself.